# The first bus in the morning vs The first morning bus

Tags: phrase-usage

Could you explain, please, "The first bus in the morning" and "The first morning bus" are the same or have a slight difference? I have asked it because in these sentences about "morning" is said twice: "morning" and "a.m.". Is it a common habbit?

> **The first bus in the morning** leaves at 5.30 a.m.
>
> **The first morning bus** leaves at 5.30 a.m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The first morning bus" leaves the possibility that there are other types of bus, some of which could be earlier.

> Night buses run every hour from 11pm to 5am the next day, but the first morning bus leaves at 5:30am, and you'll need a morning bus because the night buses don't stop at the university.

I've heard of "night buses", but I've never heard of "morning buses".

So that is possible but less likely.  You probably mean that there are no buses leaving earlier than 5:30am. And for that the first sentence is better.  But there is no need for "in the morning" and "am":

> The first bus leaves at five-thirty in the morning.

Comment: A typical UK bus company might say 'The first bus leaves at 05:30 on weekdays, 07:30 on Saturdays, and 08:30 on Sundays and public holidays". That's it. In the real world outside English books, people know what times are morning and afternoon.